# I can't see the mistake in my HTML file

Tags: html

I tried to validate my HTML code but I got this error:

> Line 157, Column 22: document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag `<div class="details">`
>
> The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in
>   which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones
>   that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned.
>   This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that
>   you've forgotten to close a previous element.
>
> One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put
>   a block-level element (such as "`<p>`" or "`<table>`") inside an inline
>   element (such as "`<a>`", "`<span>`", or "`<font>`").

but I cant see any mistake in my code, so I am asking for help...

```
<!--Bar 3-->

<div class="mosaic-block bar3">

<a href="http://www.desktopped.com/featured/2010/09/multi-d isplay-setup-with-four-systems-and-a-whole-lot-of- screen-space/" target="_blank" class="mosaic-overlay">

<div class="details">

<h4>Multi-Display Setup With Four Systems, A Wall of Screens, And 64TB Of Storage</h4>

<p>via Desktopped</p>

</div>

</a>

<a href="http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2010/12/i-am-not-hu man-portraits/" target="_blank" class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/mos aic/64tb.jpg" alt="fotka1"/></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Reduce your test case by removing elements until the error goes away - then you'll find out your culprit. Also point out where in your code sample the error message refers to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blocks can't be placed in inline elements. In this case `a` is inline, and `div` is block, so `<a><div></div></a>` is invalid HTML.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's pretty unlikely doing this will cause any problems in browsers - I'm guessing they'll just treat it as an `inline-block`.

Comment: It's invalid HTML though, so you shouldn't do it, as the output in browsers is undefined.

Comment: @millimoose The question is about validating HTML. It will work fine in the browser, but it will fail validation.

Comment: So how to make these divs link-like?

Comment: @user2295265 Place multiple `<a>` elements around the text that you want to link.

Comment: @user2295265 That should be a separate question, but the basic principle is `<div><a>..</a></div>` and make the `<a>` tag fill the entire div.

Comment: @Juhana `<a><p></p></a>` is also invalid.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt Good point; it would be better to drop the div completely and set the `<a>` tags display:block.

Comment: These suggestions fail miserably on the issue that the OP uses a `<p>` "deep" in the `<div>` which is also a block-level element, so you'd have to replace all block elements with inline elements to make the validator shut up, and then explicitly set the inline elements to `display:block;` to get the original behaviour that will work in every browser you need to care about anyway, because it's precedent that [HTML5 codifies anyway.] (http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links) It's just a whole load of extra work just do achieve nothing.

Comment: @user2295265 No, `<!DOCTYPE html>`. It's valid *now*, you (and the rest of the peanut gallery) just didn't know about the change.

Comment: Sorry, I dont get it, I dont know what to do... when I paste <!DOCTYPE html> I have non valid this: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

Comment: @user2295265 Ignore that. There's a whitelist of "valid" `http-equiv` values in the spec that should affect browser behaviour. `X-UA-Compatible` is an IE extension so it won't validate. You'll either have to deal with this minor invalidity that's even less likely to have an effect than your original one, or send a proper HTTP header instead of a meta tag.

Comment: @user2295265 Or just don't use `X-UA-Compatible`, why would you write pages against a fairly old IE version? The header doesn't mean "this page is compatible with IE8 and above", it tells *newer* versions of IE to act as IE8. It's a compatibility quirk that only makes sense for corporate intranets where everyone uses IE, it might lead to lead to broken rendering on non-IE browsers.